# How to redirect to UINavigationController from SWrevealController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWReaveealController` in my app. On click of `UITableView` to the left in app i am showing some screens. I have help option in left `UITableView`. When click on that i further showing a `UITableViewController`. In `HelpViewController` there are multiple items and user can press on any of them. So on user section i want to redirect to new screen & on back press i want to redirect to `swrevealcontroller`.
But issue is i am not able to show back button.Please tell how can i redirect to `UINavigationController` so that i can show back button.

Comment: add custom back button, and if you click that open side menu thats all\

Comment: show your stoyboard scene

Comment: adding back button not a solution

Comment: if press the back button you want ti open side menu correct

Comment: On back button i want to move to last view controller from i came but now it is reduerecting me to swrevealviewcontroller

Comment: ya in here `swrevealviewcontroller` is the root controller, how do you go on another controller, is not possible on navigation stack , if you want use present

Comment: I want to redirect to navigation controller from a swrevealcontroller so that i can maintain stack for that but swrevealcontroller does not allow to make stack of controller

Comment: ya bro it does not allow, in here you need to take the refrence of previous viewcontroller, and open manually

Comment: can u post some code?